# Open whatsapp chat for a number ionic 3/4

Tags: angular, ionic3, ionic4

I have developed an app that should open a whatsapp chat using [this plugin](https://github.com/ranjitpandit/whatsapp-phonegap-plugin.git).

I installed it using ionic CLI **ionic cordova plugin add** https://github.com/ranjitpandit/whatsapp-phonegap-plugin.git and the used it as below:

home.page.ts

```
...

declare var cordova;

...
constructor(public platform: Platform) {}

chat() {

    this.platform.ready().then(() => {

      cordova.plugins.Whatsapp.send('+263783187321');

    });

}
```

Then in home.page.html I then did this:

```
<ion-row>
    <ion-col size="12" no-padding>
      <img src="assets/imgs/chat.jpg" (click)="chat()" class="chat" />
    </ion-col>
</ion-row>
```

The problem is that it's not opening a Whatsapp chat window when I click the image. Nothing happens. Please help. Thank you

Comment: Can you put a breakpoint at `cordova.plugins.Whatsapp.send('+263783187321');` and see if the plugin is initialised at this point ? That seems to be the issue.

Comment: Yeah I used the chrome dev tools to see what it says. It just writes "Sending Whatsapp"

Answer (score 12):

This is how it works in 2019 with Ionic 4

In config.xml add:

```
<access launch-external="yes" origin="whatsapp://*" />
```

In your html:

```
<a href="whatsapp://send?phone=YOUR_NUMBER">Link<a>
```

Comment: Perfect Solution!

Comment: adding this: <access launch-external="yes" origin="whatsapp://*" />      worked!!

Comment: It`s not work here!

Answer (score 4):

It's very simple but it has a trick.

```
<a ion-button href="whatsapp//send?phone=54119998888">SEND</a>
```

but you have to allow the "whatsapp" in the config.html or it's going to be blocked (by security). So include this:

```
<access origin="whatsapp//*" launch-external="yes" />
```

be careful not to include "https://*" because it's not gonna work...

Comment: @Anuj just create a var like
let wa = "whatsapp//send?phone=" + client_phone;

and then use brackets:
<a ion-button [href]="wa">SEND</a>

Answer (score 2):

I've searched on the ionic forum's and found this with 15 votes.

By going to this URL "https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone= 573{The phone number}"
for more info - check this : https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/26000030/?category=5245251 540

Comment: Here is the solution to my problem. Upon further research I added this to config.xml

<access origin="whatsapp:*" launch-external="yes" />

Answer (score 1):

This works for me in a pwa (January 2020)

config.xml

```
<access launch-external="yes" origin="whatsapp://*" />
```

Then in your html

```
<a href="https://wa.me/whatsappnumber?text=Hello%20world">Link</a>
 or
<ion-button href="https://wa.me/whatsappnumber?text=Hola%20Mundo">
```

You should use international format (without spaces of course)

- 1 xxx xxx xxxx USA
- 52 1 xxx xxx xxxx México
- 54 9 xxx xxx xxxx Argentina

in mobile it doesn't work in serve mode but in prod it does

Answer (score 1):

If you want to call it in your js, you could simulate an `<a>` element and dynamically click it:

```
      var  element = document.createElement('a') as HTMLElement;
      element.setAttribute('href', 'https://wa.me/5959333033226?text=Hello%20How%20are%20you');
      element.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
      element.click();
```

Also you could do it on your html:

```
<a href="https://wa.me/5959333033226?text=Hello%20How%20are%20you">Link</a>
```

Set this conf inside your config.xml

```
<access launch-external="yes" origin="whatsapp://*" />
```

Answer (score 0):

This simple method works for me in my PWA both in web and mobile(android) versions without having to add access into the config file:

JS:

```
window.open(`https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=${phoneNumber}`
```

or

HTML:

```
<a href=`https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=${phoneNumber}`>Link</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Official WhatsApp Sharing Documentation](https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/android/26000030/).  It seems that they are recommending you use `wa.me`.  *Let's try it out, then!*  https://wa.me/?text=mytest.  I see...

> We couldn't find the page you were looking for

After thorough testing, I have found that the following URL formats are the only ones that allow you to use any parameter or combination of parameters:

> https://api.whatsapp.com/send?text=YourShareTextHere
>
> https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=123
>
> https://api.whatsapp.com/send?text=YourShareTextHere&phone=123

*You can always test for yourself!*

If you are interested in watching a project that keeps track of these URLs, then check us out!: https://github.com/bradvin/social-share-urls#whatsapp

[image: Social Share URLs]

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JavaScript or TypeScript then go through:

```
chat() {
this.platform.ready().then(() => {
  window.open("https://api.whatsapp.com/send/?phone=[PHONENUMBER]&text=Hi,%20Test%20Message&app_absent=0");
});}
```

OR
If you are using HTML then go through:

```
<ion-row>
<ion-col size="12" no-padding>
  <a href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send/?phone=[PHONENUMBER]&text=Hi,%20Test%20Message&app_absent=0&app_absent=0">Chat</a>
</ion-col>
```

Answer (score 0):

add a function to

```
 cally(ph) {
    window.open('https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=' + ph);
  }
```

then in your html u can use ion fab which make it neat

```
<ion-fab vertical="center" horizontal="end" slot="fixed" (click)="cally('+2349136442229')">
            <ion-fab-button>
              <ion-icon name="logo-whatsapp"></ion-icon>
            </ion-fab-button>
          </ion-fab>
```